# Nextjs Apollo Client how to set fetch cache

Tags: next.js, caching

For NextJS I fetch data from graphql.

Example here is hook for fetching menu:

```
export const useMenuItems = () => {
  const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const fetchMenuItemsData = async () => {
    const query = gql`
        query {
          menuItems(first: 25) {
          nodes {
            url
            title
            path
            parentId
            parentDatabaseId
            order
            menuItemId
            menu {
              node {
                name
                slug
                menuId
                locations
                isRestricted
                id
                databaseId
                count
              }
            }
            target
            locations
            linkRelationship
            label
            isRestricted
            id
            description
            databaseId
            cssClasses
          }
          pageInfo {
            endCursor
            hasNextPage
            hasPreviousPage
            startCursor
          }
        }
      }
    `;

    try {
      const result = await fetchWooCommerceData(query);
       
    setMenuItems(result.menuItems.nodes);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  // Call fetchMenuItemsData directly when the hook is invoked
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMenuItemsData();
  }, []);

  return { menuItems, loading, error };
};
```

The problem is on every refresh page data is again fetching and this take some time.

It is not necessary to redownload the menu every time because it does not change very often.

1. How can I add a cache here, and return the result from the cache instead of re-fetching the content every time?

I also want a cache on the server side, so that the cache is also returned to the person who visits this website for the first time.

I try use react-query, but i not see any difference.